# Why can't I load my saved game in My Boy Free?

Tags: my-boy

I was playing **Pokemon Fire Red** in *My Boy Free* on Android.
I saved the game, then when I get back on my game I click Loading State and it says you need to buy the premium *My Boy Free* to load your saved game.
Do I have to save from *My Boy Free* or from the game itself?

Comment: Did you use the in-game save feature?  Or did you use the emulator's?  The in-game one should work, according to their product description.

Comment: loading state is emulator save, not game save

Answer (score 4):

The only way for you to actually get those saves is through buying the premium version.

So your progress is basically gone until now. However you can save from the game itself, not the emulator. I play Pokemon on the emulator myself and the only way to save is through "start > save". It will mostly not influence your game until you get to some bosses where having on the spot saving makes it easier.

Answer (score 2):

You have to save from the start-menu of the game, not from the emulator's menu.

If you're afraid you've lost some progress, you can load the savedata from whichever (as far as I know) emulator, so if you get the Premium version now, you could load back what you saved in the Free version.

Comment: It's not a good idea to promote piracy here.  We don't support it at all, so I've removed that from your answer.

Comment: I haven't read all the rules yet, sorry. Won't do it again ;) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save from the game itself, as you would do when using a GBA. Save states are a feature of the emulator.

Answer (score -2):

That happens to me but I can save it on My Boy Free by saving the game as quick save then when I quick load it, it says that I have to buy premium to load when that happens I just quick load again and it plays an ad and I'm back were I saved it.